# Input file lines to array errors

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I am trying to read a file with full path and get each line and put them into an array. my code is like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void  main(){
    int Log[200];
    int i;

    For(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        getline(/var/asl/data/audit/20130502/20130502-0611/20130502-61157-UYHEZX8AAAEAAAbKRvKAAAAC, line);

        Log[i] = line;
        cout << Log[i] < "\n";
    }
}
```

but the below errors come to me and I do not how to solve them. Can anyone help me?

```
log1.cpp:7: error: :main must return int

log1.cpp: In function int main():

log1.cpp:12: error: expected primary-expression before int

log1.cpp:12: error: expected  before  token
```

Another question I have is that if I want to search a special character that is in the line that stored in arrays,(I mean search in an array) what can I do?

---

Thanks a lot dear users for your reply. I tried the code and it does not have any errors. But when i run it nothing happen. My file is not in text format. it is as like as Apache server logs format. Should it be in text format? The other question is if i put these line in arrays can i search a special value in it?
Thanks for your reply in advance.

Comment: It is `for` and not `For`. Also, add `return 0` at the end of main. Also, please format your question correctly.

Comment: If making main return 0, change the void to int, and actually define `line` somewhere. Also needs quotes on that path. I think the real answer is go back to your text book or tutor...

Comment: @tohava: No need `return 0` for `void main()`

Comment: Note that `/` is a binary operator, so `/var` must be a syntax error, and `var` is an undefined variable name.  You probably had in mind using a string `"/var/asl/data/audit/20130502/20130502-0611/20130502-61157-UYHEZX8AAAEAAAbKRvKAAAAC"` as a file name, but fixing that leaves you with an incorrect invocation of `getline()`.

Comment: @ABFORCE: it's `int main()`, never `void main()`.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: I replaced it with `int main()` in my answer

Comment: Lacks the minimal understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Salam ,Try this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("example.txt"); //file address
    string Log[200];
    int i=0;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( myfile.good() )
        {
            getline (myfile,line);
            Log[i] = line;
            i++;
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be using `while (getline(myfile, line))` because your code adds one line too many when the `getline()` encounters EOF.  You probably get the last line repeated in the array.  It would also be sensible to use `while (getline(myfile, line) && i < 200)` or something similar to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: Maybe the question owner assumption is the number of lines is always less than 200

Comment: But teaching good programming skills helps them avoid making assumptions, or crashing when those assumptions are violated.  And you know that ASSUME makes an ass out of you and me...Generally, it is a good idea to fix the easily fixed minor issues.  Sorry to nitpick on you.  You do in fact have an upvote from me already.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You're right sir, But I think here is not a place to teaching C++ programming. Also I believe that the strategy of a question must be kept. Because it is so important for it's owner.At the end excuse me for any irreverence.